# Workshopping Help: "Should I allow a Player to use a premade character?"

Tags: discussion, dnd-5e, workshop-question

I have a question I want to ask and would like to run it by the community before I actually ask it so I can obtain feedback.

Here is my question:

> ### Should I allow a Player to use a premade character?
>
> In my 5th edition campaign based in the Eberron world we’ve recently obtained a new player. The player in question would like to play a premade rogue character. (I have no clue where he got the character from)
>
> Character name: Bjorn Lightfoot
>
> (STR: 15)   (DEX: 17)   (CON:16)  (INT: 14)   (WIS: 14)   (CHA: 16)
>
> Everyone in the campaign is playing a character they made themselves and fleshed out the backstory to. The new player just has to level up their character to level 4. I want to deny the character he is proposing because it seems like a pretty overpowered ability score setup despite the fact that most premade characters that are official are quite balanced. The highest score among any of the other players is a 15 which is only slightly higher than his lowest score. When I asked the 3 veteran players it was very undecided with one agreeing with me and one against me while the other was not really supplying their opinion.
>
> I really don’t want to be jumping to conclusions so should I allow this person to use his character regardless of the unfair advantage I believe it gives him?

Is there anything I should add or change to make this question actually answerable?

Comment: WHat is your concern? Did they use the same stat creation system? WHat about this character makes you worried?

Comment: they didn't use any stat creation system that I was able to see

Comment: Are the stat values equivalent to your other players? WHat is this "overpowered ability" is this not a build based off the the rules? Is it a class/subclass from a third party?

Comment: his scores are quite a bit higher than what everyone else in the party has. we usually roll for our ability scores, and sure he's able to get those scores with luck, but the highest score in the party is a 15. and his lowest is only 14 which has to be insanely good luck in my opinion.

Comment: What's your rolling method?

Comment: Roll 4 x 6 sided dice.
Remove the lowest dice result.
Add up the remaining numbers to get an ability score.

Comment: Related issue on [rolling for ability scores](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133350/how-can-i-avoid-problems-that-arise-from-rolling-ability-scores)

Comment: should I add the rolling method in the question?

Comment: and the related question doesn't answer my question

Comment: @NautArch is the question understandable and have the ability to be answered?

Comment: I put up an answer for a revised question - but I'm also uncertain that the question I linked above won't help you figure out what to do, either :P

Comment: Related on [How to persuade players not to cheat](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/158612/how-to-persuade-players-not-to-cheat)

Comment: I'm assuming asking both is off the table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142680/discussion-between-nautarch-and-argo).

Comment: A link to your resulting question on RPG.SE, for posterity: [How to handle rolled stats when I think one player cheated on theirs?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/204595/33569)

Answer (score 2):

The average roll that would result in that "pregen" is **14.98**, while the expected roll would be [about 13](https://anydice.com/articles/4d6-drop-lowest/).

Is it your question if that character was created with an official alternate system like... point buy or where it comes from? Then you might ask along the lines of: **"Is there a way to identify the most likely character creation method of these statistics?"**

Is it your problem that you believe that there was cheating or very misunderstood or alternate rules applied for that creation? Then you might ask about an apparent cheating or misunderstood rules problem. [BTW: 13-15 is the expected area for 4d6 not dropping.](https://anydice.com/program/2d95a)

Is it your problem to figure out if the player understood the rules of character creation and you can't check the character for correctness? Ask something aiming at: **"I can't follow the character creation of a PC. How can I verify it was actually done correctly?"**